# AWS Lambda Webhook event handling, NodeJS to Python

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I got this NodeJS code from a coworker.
This code is in AWS lambda and handles incoming events which are sent per webhook.
Inside this code I specify a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream which then sends the data to a bucket.
I have the delivery stream in between to do some zipping and adding partition.
2nd thing that is important in this code is the part where I take the body of the incoming event and send it as json to the delivery stream.

Can someone help me to interpret this code to python?

```js
const AWS = require( 'aws-sdk' );

const firehose = new AWS.Firehose();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
    try {
        await firehose
            .putRecord({
                DeliveryStreamName: 'foo',
                Record: {
                    Data:event.body
                }
            })
            .promise();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: `Cannot process event: ${error}`
        };
    }
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            ack: new Date().getTime()
        })
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boto3 Python AWS SDK](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime

client = boto3.client('firehose')

def handler(event): 
    print(json.dumps(event, indent=4))
    try:
        response = client.put_record(
        DeliveryStreamName='string',
        Record={
            'Data': event.body
        }
    )
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps(f'Cannot process event: {e}')
        }

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({ 'ack': datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') })
    }
```

Comment: is there a possibility to send an incoming event to different buckets or delivery streams, depending on what kind of event it is ? Right now I send the payload to one bucket. Or is it not a good idea to have one lambda for all events ?